# PHP pass variable outside of function without global variables

Tags: php, function

Let's say I have a function in php like this:

```
<?php function hello() {
   $x = 2;
}
```

and I want to use that variable outside of this function without using global, since I've heard it's a bad idea because of it's security issues. (right?).

Anyway, what is the best way to get this value out? I would be able to do this in java by using "this". But not sure how that works in PHP. Thanks.

Update:

This is the code I needed help with:

```
<?php
require('includes/connect.php');

function connectHouseObjects() {

        global $mysqli;
        /* Register a prepared statement */
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT x FROM house_room1 WHERE user_id = ?')) {

                /* Bind parametres */
                $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);

                /* Insert the parameter values */
                $user_id = 1;

                /* Execute the query */
                $stmt->execute();

                /* Bind resultatet */
                $stmt->bind_result($x);

                while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                    //looping through the x's and y's
                }

                /* Close statement */
                $stmt->close();
        return $x;
            } else {
                /* Something went wrong */
                echo 'Something went terrible wrong'     . $mysqli->error;
            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: Just return the variable from the function.

Comment: @JohnConde so taking the example above, would I need to return it there? and what if I have several values?

Comment: `return $x`. `$x` can be an array which holds multiple values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

John Conde is right but to show you the code it would be

```
<?php 

function hello() {
   $x = 2;
   return $x;
}

$var = hello();
echo $var;

?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simply return your data:

```
function hello() {
   $x = 2;
   return $x;
}
```

and use its result wherever you want;

```
$x=hello();
```

Answer (score 4):

Take this for example:

```
<?php 

function hello(){
    $x=2;
    //this is where you get it out
    return $x;
}
//here we are outside the function
$x = hello();
//$x now equals 2;
?>
```

Returning the variable from the function allows you to call the function and assign it outside.

Going more object oriented:

```
<?php

class Talk
{
    protected $message;

    public function setMessage($message){
        //this will set your class variable to what ever is in $message
        $this->message = $message;
    }
    public function getMessage()
    {
        //This will give you what ever your current message is
        return $this->message;
    }
}
//Then to use this you could do
$talk = new Talk();
//That sets up $talk to be an instance of the talk class

$talk->setMessage('Hello');
//This will then sets the message in talk to hello then to retrieve it just do

$message = $talk->getMessage();

//Now outside the class we have a variable $message that contains 'Hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also create a class, just like in Java, and use a class variable that can be accessed from other functions in that class.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return the value outside the function:

```
<?php
function hello() {
    $x = 2;
    return $x;
}

$x = hello();
```

If you want to return **more than one value**, you can use the `list()` function, while returning values as an array:

```
<?php
function hello() {
    $x = 2;
    $y = 3;
    return array($x, $y);
}

list($x, $y) = hello();
```

You can find more information about the `list()` in the **[PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)**